# How to deal with different style of font in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a project and came across this data with different style of font in a column.

If you look at the revenue column, '' is present instead of 'to'

[Datframe Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSzA3.png)

I tried to replace it by

```
df['Revenue'] = [x.replace('', ' to ') for x in df['Revenue']]
```

but no luck..

Any suggestion of how to deal with this?

edit:

```
analyst[['Revenue']].head(5).to_dict('split')
```

returns

```
> {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 'columns': ['Revenue'],
 'data': [['$100 to $500 million (USD)'],
  ['$2 to $5 billion (USD)'],
  ['Unknown / Non-Applicable'],
  ['$50 to $100 million (USD)'],
  ['$100 to $500 million (USD)']]}
```

Comment: Welcome, it is easier for us to test solutions if you post the df sample as a code block. You can get it with `df.head().to_dict('split')`

Comment: @RichieV thank you for the suggestion, unforunately, it appears as a normal looking 'to' instead of '' :(

Comment: @prayer_in_c I think your original code `df['Revenue'] = [x.replace('', ' to ') for x in df['Revenue']]` would have worked. Did you ran it without typo then append the first 5 lines to the question?

Comment: @yibo yes I have, didn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalize unicode characters to ascii as follows:

sample input:

```
    Revenue
0  200300
1  200300
2  200300
```

code

```
# create data:
# import pandas as pd
# df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Revenue=["200300"]*3))

import unicodedata
df["Revenue"] = df.Revenue.apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", x))
```

output

```
    Revenue
0  200to300
1  200to300
2  200to300
```